# Cordova stops when trying to initialize phonertc

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonertc

I'm trying to use the PhoneRTC plugin on my Ionic project. I've followed this [guide](https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-an-audio-calling-app-with-ionic-and-phonertc/), but everything stops when calling:

`var session = new cordova.plugins.phonertc.Session(config);`
There are no errors, it just stops.

Code:

```
function call(isInitiator, peer_id) {
    console.log('Før config...');
    var config = {
        isInitiator : isInitiator,
        turn : {
            host : 'turn:<url>'
        },
        stream : {
            audio : true,
            video : false
        }
    };
    console.log('Before');
    //Initiate call
    var session = new cordova.plugins.phonertc.Session(config);
    console.log('After');
    session.on('sendMessage', function(data) {
        SocketService.emit('sendMessage', {
        id : $scope.id,
        peer_id : $scope.peer_id,
        type : 'phonertc_handshake',
        data : JSON.stringify(data)
    });
});
```

Logcat:

```
I/chromium(12959): [INFO:CONSOLE(57)] "Before", source: file:///android_asset/www/callController.js (57)
I/chromium(12959): [INFO:CONSOLE(21162)] "[object Object]", source: file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js (21162)</code>
```

Do anyone have an idea of what is wrong?

(The plugin is referred in platform/android/res/config.xml)

Comment: I've never used this plugin but i've experienced issues with other things where I wasn't getting a callback or an error and it turned out I was missing a URL off the whitelist in the `config.xml`. Does this plugin need to whitelist a server or some URL do you think?

Comment: I don't think I have to whitelist any servers. The plugin connects to my own node server (socket.io), and my own turn server. Here is the only reference to PhoneRTC in platform/android/res/xml/config.xml:
    <feature name="PhoneRTCPlugin">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.dooble.phonertc.PhoneRTCPlugin" />
    </feature>

Comment: And this is the CSP I'm using: <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; media-src *"/>

Comment: My config was wrong. It should be 'streams', not 'stream'. My bad!